# My sendmail log get TLS setup failed

Tags: perl, sendmail, nagios

I setup my nagios in docker container,and It working.and sendmail can send mail to me.

I find it can't send message to me one day,and I see the Log of sendmail,I get this error

`nagios sendEmail.pl[15471]: ERROR => TLS setup failed: SSL connect attempt failed because of handshake problems error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure`

during this time,I just stop and restart my nagios container

the packages of libio-socket-ssl-perl and libnet-ssleay-perl perl also have installed.

How can I slove this problem??

Thanks very much

Comment: Unrelated but I guess you're using Net::SMTP::TLS which is too old.

Comment: @ChankeyPathak: Net::SMTP::TLS is not used in this code but the error (wrong use of SSL_version) is the same in both cases.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Ah I see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean with `sendEmail.pl` [this script with the last update from 2009](http://caspian.dotconf.net/menu/Software/SendEmail/) then you are using unsupported and broken software. It might work if you change the following line in the script:

```
-   if (! IO::Socket::SSL->start_SSL($SERVER, SSL_version => 'SSLv3 TLSv1')) {
+   if (! IO::Socket::SSL->start_SSL($SERVER)) {
```

Reason for this change is that the setting of `SSL_version` in the code was wrong from the beginning, only that 7 years ago IO::Socket::SSL did not complain about it but simply used the first setting `SSLv3`. But since 4 years IO::Socket::SSL is stricter and complains about the wrong usage. Apart from that `SSLv3` would not work in many cases anyway today because the protocol is disabled for security reasons.

Comment: Thank you very much.....It must be work,I change the command of  the send mail, I add the option -o tls=no before your answer。Thank you。